# How to handle and use the default application of android programatically

Tags: android

Can anyone explain me, how can I handle and use the default applications of my Android device programatically.
Also how can I get all the app information installed on my device  and also unistalling them progromatically.
If possible kindly give me fews links to understand and using these things properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "default app" I assume you mean a Home replacement. There is [a Google sample here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html) as well as [ADW Launcher](http://code.google.com/p/adw-launcher-android/) and also the [source for the Android launcher](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Launcher2.git;a=tree)

Comment: actually I want to show the internal information of all the apps in the device and also other device information like battery usage,internal memory,RAM details,apps details etc.. in one of  my Android application .How its possible ....?

Comment: That's not what you asked! You need to ask questions much more clearly. I suggest you ask another.

Comment: Now Can you give me some ideas over the topic. How can I access the internal inforamtion of the device and app installed.......

Comment: Not here, no, as that's not the question. The answers on a question need to match the question. As you're now asking a second, different question, you need to post a new question.